# Is a $4×4$ Latin square possible whose trace-sum is 7 or 9 or 13 or 15?

Tags: latin-square

A Latin square with trace-sum $11$ is : 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&4&2&3\\
2&3&4&1\\
4&1&3&2\\
3&2&1&4\end{bmatrix}$$
Is trace sum $7/9/5/13/15$ possible in some other arrangement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By swapping numbers in the given arrangement, we can trivially derive trace sums of $7$ (main diagonal reads $2113$), $9$ ($3114$) and $13$ ($2443$).

But trace sums of $5$ and $15$ are not possible, for there would have to be three $1$s or three $4$s on the main diagonal respectively, forcing the fourth number to be the same as the other three by the Latin square property and thereby not yielding the desired trace sum.

Comment: Can you answer a similar question : Is a 5 cross 5 latin square matrix possible whose trace-sum is 6 or 7 or 9 or 22 or 23 or 24 ?

Comment: @ShaliniTomar Please ask that in another question and upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: I did that ....:)

Comment: @ Parcly Taxel Here is the new question :  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608980/is-a-5%c3%975-latin-square-possible-whose-trace-sum-is-6-or-7-or-9-or-22-or-23-or-24